# Simple_Fields_For not saving data of child record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, simple-form

I am currently trying to fix the relationship between delivery, delivery_orders and orders model. I've been trying all day to save a nested form that stores the orders inside of the delivery_orders table. Essentially, I want to be able to create deliveries, and then add orders to the deliveries through the delivery_order model. Normal users create orders, but Managers handle deliveries for those orders. So far, I've been unable to save the nested simple_form_for section for delivery_order model. It keep returning nil, even though the relationship is setup to support the transaction. One side note, I am unable to read the attributes of the orders through the delivery model. The code that I wrote is below. Structure User -> Order -> Manager Delivery[Delivery_order] -> Truck[Delivery]

delivery.rb

```
class Delivery < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :warehouse, optional: true
  belongs_to :truck, optional: true
  has_one :delivery_order
  has_one :order_tracker
  has_many :breads
  #after_create :decrement_bread_stock
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_order

end
```

deliveryorder.rb

```
class DeliveryOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :delivery_order
  belongs_to :delivery, optional: true
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, :dependent => :destroy, optional: true
  belongs_to :delivery_order, optional: true
  has_one :bread
  has_one :order_tracker, :dependent => :destroy
  after_create :build_order_tracker
  geocoded_by :address, :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj) {obj.client_address.present? && obj.client_address_changed?}

  def address
    [client_address, client_state].compact.join(', ')
  end

end
```

deliveries_controller.rb

```
class DeliveriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_delivery, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  # GET /deliveries
  # GET /deliveries.json
  def index
    @deliveries = Delivery.all
  end

  # GET /deliveries/1
  # GET /deliveries/1.json
  def show; end

  # GET /deliveries/new
  def new
    @delivery = Delivery.new
    @delivery.build_delivery_order
    @delivery_orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /deliveries/1/edit
  def edit; end

  # POST /deliveries
  # POST /deliveries.json
  def create
    @delivery = current_manager.warehouse.deliveries.build(delivery_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery.save
        format.html { redirect_to @delivery, notice: 'Delivery was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @delivery }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @delivery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /deliveries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /deliveries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery.update(delivery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @delivery, notice: 'Delivery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @delivery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @delivery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /deliveries/1
  # DELETE /deliveries/1.json
  def destroy
    @delivery.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to deliveries_url, notice: 'Delivery was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_delivery
    @delivery = Delivery.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def delivery_params
    params.require(:delivery).permit(:delivery_date, :delivery_on_time, delivery_order_attributes: %i[order_1 order_2 order_3 order_4 delivery_id order_id], orders_attributes: [:order_id])
  end
end
```

delivery _form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <%= simple_form_for(@delivery) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Estimated Delivery Date</label>
      <%= f.input :delivery_date, class: 'form-control', label: false %>
    </div>
    <%= simple_fields_for :delivery_order, @delivery.delivery_order do |d| %>
      <div class="form-control">
        <label>Delivery Order 1</label>
        <%= d.input :order_1, collection: @delivery_orders, :label_method => lambda {|order| "Order Id: #{order.id} | Client Name: #{order.client_name} | Client Address: #{order.client_address} | Bread Type: #{order.bread_type} | Bread Quantity: #{order.bread_quantity}" }, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, prompt: 'Add your first order to the delivery', class: 'form-control', label: false %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Delivery Order 2</label>
        <%= d.input :order_2, collection: @delivery_orders, :label_method => lambda {|order| "Order Id: #{order.id} | Client Name: #{order.client_name} | Client Address: #{order.client_address} | Bread Type: #{order.bread_type} | Bread Quantity: #{order.bread_quantity}" }, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, prompt: 'Add your second order to the delivery', class: 'form-control', label: false %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Delivery Order 3</label>
        <%= d.input :order_3, collection: @delivery_orders, :label_method => lambda {|order| "Order Id: #{order.id} | Client Name: #{order.client_name} | Client Address: #{order.client_address} | Bread Type: #{order.bread_type} | Bread Quantity: #{order.bread_quantity}" }, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, prompt: 'Add your third order to the delivery', class: 'form-control', label: false %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Delivery Order 4</label>
        <%= d.input :order_4, collection: @delivery_orders, :label_method => lambda {|order| "Order Id: #{order.id} | Client Name: #{order.client_name} | Client Address: #{order.client_address} | Bread Type: #{order.bread_type} | Bread Quantity: #{order.bread_quantity}" }, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, prompt: 'Add your fourth order to the delivery', class: 'form-control', label: false %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

orders _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <%= f.input :client_name, required: true, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Zip Code</label>
    <%= f.input :client_zip_code, required: true, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Address</label>
    <%= f.input :client_address, required: true, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>State</label>
    <%= f.input :client_state, required: true, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose a Bread</label>
    <%= f.collection_select :bread_name, collection: Bread.all, required: true, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

trucks_controller.rb

```
class TrucksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_truck, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_manager!
  # GET /trucks
  # GET /trucks.json
  def index
    @trucks = Truck.all
  end

  # GET /trucks/1
  # GET /trucks/1.json
  def show;
  end

  # GET /trucks/new
  def new
    @truck = Truck.new
    @deliveries = Delivery.all
  end

  # GET /trucks/1/edit
  def edit;
  end

  # POST /trucks
  # POST /trucks.json
  def create
    @truck = current_manager.warehouse.trucks.build(truck_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @truck.save
        format.html {redirect_to @truck, notice: 'Truck was successfully created.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @truck}
      else
        format.html {render :new}
        format.json {render json: @truck.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /trucks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /trucks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @truck.update(truck_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @truck, notice: 'Truck was successfully updated.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @truck}
      else
        format.html {render :edit}
        format.json {render json: @truck.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /trucks/1
  # DELETE /trucks/1.json
  def destroy
    @truck.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to trucks_url, notice: 'Truck was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_truck
    @truck = Truck.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def truck_params
    params.require(:truck).permit(:delivery_total, :lon, :lat, :delivery_id, :loaded_date, :truck_driver_name, :current_street_address, :current_city, :current_state, :current_country)
  end
end
```

truck.rb

```
class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :warehouse, optional: true
  has_many :deliveries
end
```

trucks _form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <%= simple_form_for(@truck) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label>Loaded Date (Click Box Below)</label>
        <%= f.input :loaded_date, as: :date_time_picker, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Tap to view calendar <i class: 'fa fa-hand-o-up'></i>", label: false %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :delivery_total, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :truck_driver_name, class: 'form-control btn btn-outline-primary' %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :current_street_address, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :current_city, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :current_state, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :current_country, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= f.input :delivery_id, collection: @deliveries, :label_method => lambda {|delivery| "Estimated Delivery Date: #{delivery.delivery_date} | Order Id: #{delivery.id}"}, value_method: :id, label: "Delivery Jobs", include_blank: false, prompt: 'Add a delivery to the truck' %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hiya - so it helps us if we see what you've tried, and what the errors were that you saw in the console/log-file. Can you add those (to your question, NOT here in comments), along with the params that came through when you submitted the form? Just OTTOMH this looks suspicious: `@delivery_orders = Order.all` you are using simple-form to generate a form for a `delivery_order` and yet if you populate that with an `order` it will be trying to generate a form for an `order` not a `delivery_order` (because AFAIK it uses the name of the model class, not the name of the variable that you store it in).

Comment: I'm simply trying to grab existing orders, and save them into the delivery form. So, that the delivery object can be loaded into the truck.

Comment: yes I realise that... but I still need what i asked for. Can you please supply the things that I asked for? It really helps us to help you! Have you also thought about the thing I mentioned about the different models?

Comment: I will update very soon I'm making a few changes to the relationships for the models.

Comment: Why do you need the DeliveryOrder model. Your Delivery could `has_many :orders` and an Order could `belongs_to :delivery`;